# MS Access: Locking Specific Forms Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am creating a database which has some forms restricted for some users and some are accessible depending on their user type (For example: Admin, User, Guest). I created a visual basic code on the On Load Event of my Main Form and I also call the user type in that form (txtUserType). I want the Admin form to be accessible only by the admins but when I logged in as an admin, the admin form is still locked. Any help on how I can resolve this?

I created a string in my login form for me to be able to call the value of the UserType in my main form. Here is the code:

```
Dim UserType As String
UserType = DLookup("[UserType]", "tbl_Worker", "[LoginID] = '" & 
Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")
Forms![frm_Home]![txtUserType] = UserType
```

And now the textbox in my main form which is txtUserType shows the user type of who ever is logged in.

My code in the main form is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If Me.txtUserType = "Admin" Then
Me.NavigationButton419.Enabled = True
Else
Me.NavigationButton419.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code and see why "Me.txtUserType" does not equal "Admin".

Comment: @andrew It says that Me.txtUserType = Null but clearly there is a value in that textbox in the main form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I also call the user type in that form` - you don't show that code or what event it gets called from - THAT's most likely the cause of your problem

Comment: I'll edit the question so you'll see it

Comment: Where is that code located? The main form (frm_home) has to be open when you try to set the text box control on it from the login. You just define UserType as a global and then change your code to `If UserType = "Admin" Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and report back any issues.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    NavigationButton419.Enabled = IsAdmin(txtUsername.Value)
End Sub

Private Function IsAdmin(ByVal Username As String)
    IsAdmin = (Nz(DLookup("[UserType]", "tbl_Worker", "[LoginID] = '" & Username & "'"), "Guest") = "Admin")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

3 possible suggestions:

Change the event where you are testing

i.e. instead of

```
  Form_Load
```

use

```
  Form_Current
```

Or better yet:

Store the txtUserType Field on a totally different Form (could also be a form that is open as a hidden form)

```
If Forms!myHiddenForm.txtUserType = "Admin" Then
...
```

Or a neater way:
create a VBA function in a module

```
Public Function isSuperUser() As Boolean

If Forms!myHiddenForm.txtUserType = "Admin" Then
    isSuperUser = True
Else
    isSuperUser = False
End if

End Function
```

then back on your form

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Me.NavigationButton419.Enabled = isSuperUser()

End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried all three and everything is still locked though I signed in as Admin. On your third suggestion, I put a breakpoint on the Me.NavigationButton419.Enabled = isSuperUser() and it says that Me.NavigationButton419.Enabled = False. It still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

As I experimented on different ways to create a solution to the problem and based on other's suggestions, I came up with this and it worked as I wanted to. Here is the code:

```
Dim UserType As String

UserType = DLookup("[UserType]", "tbl_Worker", "[LoginID] = '" & 
Me.txtUsername.Value & "'")

DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_Home"

Forms![frm_Home]![txtUserType] = UserType

If Form_frm_Home.txtUserType = "Admin" Then
Form_frm_Home.NavigationButton438.Enabled = True
Else
Form_frm_Home.NavigationButton438.Enabled = False
End If
```